# Jquery Datatables Selected Checkbox to Input Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have here a Datatable with 3 columns: Checkbox, Name, and SSNTIN, when I select rows then click Submit, their SSNTIN will output in '#txtSSNTIN' input field like "1001,1002,1003" but my problem is only the selected rows in the current page of my Datatable are being outputted in the input field, when I go to another page there is an indicator that the other rows from the previous page are still selected but only current page is outputting, please help

**Datatable**

```
Namestable = $('#NamesDatatable').DataTable({
    'select': {
        'style': 'multi',
    },
    'columnDefs': [{
        'targets': 0,
        'searchable': false,
        'orderable': false,
        'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'+data.ssn_or_tin+'">';
        }
    }],
    'order': [[1, 'asc']],
    "ajax": {
        "url": '/Home/GetAllCusname',
        "type": "POST",
        "datatype": "json",
        "data": function (d) {
            d.searchParameters = {};
            d.searchParameters.name = $('#txtName').val();
        }
    },
    "columns": [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '',
        },
        { "data": "name", "autoWidth": true },
        { "data": "ssn_or_tin", "autoWidth": true }
    ]
});
```

**Submit Button**

```
$('#btnSubmit').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var searchNames = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    $('#txtSSNTIN').val(searchNames);
});
```

Comment: do `var searchNames = $('input:checkbox :checked').map(function () {`  or  `var searchNames = $('input[type="checkbox"] :checked').map(function () {`

Comment: @AlivetoDie It's not working, no result in the '#txtSSNTIN' input field

Comment: you need to create a fiddle example link of your problem so that we can check and let you know